# X:uid in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

what is the use of X:Uid attribute in silverlight controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As a practical example, we have used x:Uid for UI automation purposes.**

Tools like UISpy see what you stuff in the value of the x:Uid attribute ... as the AutomationID property. See this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa349646.aspx) for more info. In other words, it identifies the controls that you wish to automate/test and allows you to actually do that automation/testing.

In fact, the above is the only reason we have ever used this attribute.

Now, in my case, I am talking about the WPF applications I've worked on, and I can see from your question that you are asking about the Silverlight controls. Maybe Silverlight doesn't (yet) have a way to automate/test the controls in the same manner ... in that case, Austin Lamb's answer makes a lot of sense. Many things are done in Silverlight that don't have any apparent purpose ... other than for compatibility reasons (so you have less work to do when making controls that work on both platforms).

Answer (score 1):

x:Uid is ignored by the Silverlight runtime, it is there for WPF compatibility and to ease sharing of XAML and tools between the two runtimes.

Comment: I see you work on the SL team, any idea why Jeff Wilcox mentioned an increased support for x:Uid....http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/03/silverlight4-new-parser/ as though it had value within SL4?

Comment: Because the parser used to error out if x:Uid was found, I believe.  So this way tools and shared XAML are better supported, even though at runtime the value is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

[x:Uid Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613571.aspx)

> Provides a unique identifier for
>   markup elements. In many scenarios,
>   this unique identifier is used by XAML
>   localization processes and tools.

Comment: i need the pratical implementation

Comment: It states..."This unique identifier is used by XAML localization processes and tools" what more are you looking for?